# Error : Constant or type identifier expected

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am trying to use an External DLL function in my delphi 7 program. I have an example in C in which DLL file called.

In C it is defined like this

```
#define SerNumAddress 0x1080

HINSTANCE hDLL430;                          // handle of DLL
static FARPROC pMSPGangInitCom  = NULL; // pointer to DLL function
```

and in delphi i write

```
unit msp430d;

interface
USES windows, event, paras;

const

SerNumAddress = $1080  ;
pmspganginitcom:FARPROC = nil;

TYPE
hDLL430 = HINSTANCE;

implementation

end.
```

But I am getting `constant or type identifier expected` error.

Comment: In the C code, `hDLL430` is not a type. It's a variable with type `HINSTANCE`. Likewise, `pMSPGangInitCom` is not a constant; the C code declares it as a variable. The `static` keyword means the variable is accessible only by the current file, akin to declaring a variable in the `implementation` section of a Delphi unit instead of the `interface` section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the use of `HINSTANCE`.

In the `System` unit there is a global variable named `HInstance` that represents the module handle that contains the code being executed. You are trying to use `HINSTANCE` as a type. Because of the variable `HInstance`, a type named `HINSTANCE` would clash. So instead that type is translated as `HINST` in the `Windows` unit.

So, the following code would compile:

```
type
  hDLL430 = HINST;
```

However, in my view, it would be more normal to use `HMODULE` these days. See [What is the difference between HINSTANCE and HMODULE?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/14/155107.aspx)

Consider the comment in the C code which says:

```
HINSTANCE hDLL430; // handle of DLL
```

Well, if you look at the declarations of [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) and [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx), you'll see that the DLL module handle is represented by `HMODULE`. So I would translate this code as:

```
type
  hDLL430 = HMODULE;
```

Furthermore, rather than using `FARPROC` I would opt to declare a function pointer that contained the parameters, return value and calling convention to allow the compiler to enforce type safety.

Comment: Hi david  thanks for your reply. How can i declare a function pointer instead of FAPROC and which one i should use  because both method is new to me.  @davidHeffeman

Comment: `pmspganginitcom: function(foo: Integer): Integer; stdcall;` but I've guessed the types. You may be better defining a type in case you have to cast the value returned by GetProcAddress.